# RegEx capture group that excludes a specific pattern

Tags: regex

I am trying to come up with a RegEx pattern that takes strings that look like this:

```
KEEP_THIS_L_1234  
KEEP_THIS_R_12  
KEEP_THIS
```

and returns a capture group with this result:

```
KEEP_THIS
KEEP_THIS
KEEP_THIS
```

So far I have tried `/^(\w+)(?=_(L|R))(?=_\d{0,4})/`, but this pattern only returns the capture groups for the first two instances:

```
KEEP_THIS
KEEP_THIS
```

Can someone help me understand what I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make the last two groups optional, like this:

```
/^(\w+?)((_(L|R))(_\d{0,4}))?$/
```

Your desired result will always be in $1.

This has the advantage that your other data captured (if any) will be in groups $2 and $3.

Comment: @NickC, you're welcome and welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't forget to mark the answer by checking on it :)

Comment: @alphabravo, I think it's because you had extra white space before the carriage returns

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex like below.

```
^(\w+)(?=(?:_[LR]_\d{0,4})|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hN1bS2/1)